# Apply CSS styles to descendants but not if a child is of a certain selector

Tags: css, angular, sass

*I'm asking this question for an Angular application but I believe this relates to CSS in general.*

I have an Angular component with a number of child components, and each has the standard view encapsulation. As an example, I want to change the `line-height` of all `p` tags within the parent component, including children components, to a different value.

Something like the following works for this (SCSS):

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep {
        p {
            line-height: 2em;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to change this style to effect a certain child component, let's call it `foobar`. So I hoped something like the following would work:

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep {
        :not(foobar) {
            p {
                line-height: 2em;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand this doesn't work because the `p` element can be descendants of other elements and so the rule is still applied.

I also know I can do the following:

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep {
        p:not(foobar p) {
            line-height: 2em;
        }    
    }
}
```

However, if I want to override a number of elements/classes etc. then this becomes rather unmanageable.

---

So question is; is there a good/modern way to do this using SCSS or more modern selectors? Anything on the Angular side that can help (aside from turning off viewEncapsulation)?

Comment: can you not use ngStyle and only apply the style if the condition is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using a SCSS mixin:

```
@mixin not-foobar {
    &:not(foobar #{nth(nth(&, 1), length(nth(&, 1)))}) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

with example usage:

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep {
        p {
            @include not-foobar {
                line-height: 2em;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

The mixin basically creates the `p:not(foobar p) {` selector but means I only need to include the mixin where it's needed, rather than using the selector and possibly setting it incorrectly.

The `#{nth(nth(&, 1), length(nth(&, 1)))})` part of the mixin basically selects the immediate parent. Using just `&` set the whole parent which led to unwanted side effects in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how deeply you want to customize the overall styles of the `parent` and some `child` components from the parent component but, you could handle that by creating another stylesheet and adding it to the parent's styles array like the following:

**parent component**

```html
<p>Parent paragraph</p>
<child-one></child-one>
<child-two></child-two>
```

**child one**

```html
<p>Child one paragraph</p>
```

**child two**

```html
<p>Child two paragraph</p>
```

**extra-styles.scss**

```css
:ng-deep {
  child-one {
    p {
      color: green;
    }
  }

  child-two {
    p {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

**parent.styles.scss**

```css
p {
  color: cyan;
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: './parent.html',
  styles: ['./parent.styles.scss', 'extra-styles.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zdnyaz?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)